# Multiply by orthogonal matrices and obtain diagonalizability

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, orthogonal-matrices

It is possible to show that if a  $ n \times n $ real matrix $ A $ verifies that  $ PA $ is diagonalizable for all real invertible matrix  $ P $ , then  $ A=0 $ , because all the matrices that are equivalent to  $ A $ are diagonalizable.
I tried it with keeping only orthogonal matrices in the initial hypothesis (instead of simply invertible), and using SVD, it still works  :  the result is the same.
Now, I want to check if it is still true keeping only special orthogonal matrices. When  $ n $  is odd, it works because  $  \mathcal{O}(n) = \mathcal{SO}(n) \cup (-\mathcal{SO}(n))  $ , but I have no solution for  $ n $  even.

Comment: Are you assuming $n>1$, and when you say "diagonalizable" do you mean "diagonalizable over the reals"? (otherwise the second claim fails with $A=I$, since every real orthogonal matrix is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$).

Comment: Yes, over the reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $n=2$; then $\mathcal{SO}(2)$ is the set of rotations and $\mathcal{O}(2)\setminus\mathcal{SO}(2)$ is the set of reflections. Choose $A$ to be any reflection (eg $\mathrm{diag}(1,-1)$). If $P$ is a rotation then $PA$ is a reflection, which is diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$. Thus the claim fails for $n=2$.

The claim does hold for $n>2$. Indeed write $A=UDV^{-1}$ where $U,V\in\mathcal{SO}(n)$ and $D$ is diagonal. For any $O\in\mathcal{SO}(n)$, we have $VOU^{-1}\in\mathcal{SO}(n)$, so $VOU^{-1}A$ is diagonalizable by assumption. Hence
$$
  V^{-1}(VOU^{-1}A)V=OD
$$
is diagonalizable.

Write $D=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$. First suppose the rank of $D$ is at least $2$. wlog suppose $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\neq0$. Let
$$
  O'=\begin{bmatrix}
    0&\mathrm{sgn}(\lambda_2)&0\\
    -\mathrm{sgn}(\lambda_1)&0&0\\
    0&0&\mathrm{sgn}(\lambda_2)\mathrm{sgn}(\lambda_1)
  \end{bmatrix}\in\mathcal{SO}(3),
$$
$$
  O=\begin{bmatrix}O'&0\\0&I_{n-3}\end{bmatrix}\in\mathcal{SO}(n).
$$
Then
$$
  OD=\begin{bmatrix}X&0\\0&*\end{bmatrix}
$$
where
$$
  X=\begin{bmatrix}0&|\lambda_2|\\-|\lambda_1|&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now $X$ is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$, so neither is $OD$, a contradiction.

Next suppose $D$ has rank $1$. wlog suppose $\lambda_1\neq0$ and $\lambda_i=0$ for $i>1$. Let
$$
  O'=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}\in\mathcal{SO}(2),
$$
$$
  O=\begin{bmatrix}O'&0\\0&I_{n-2}\end{bmatrix}\in\mathcal{SO}(n).
$$
Now $OD$ is nilpotent and nonzero, again contradicting $OD$ being diagonalizable. Hence $D=0$, so $A=0$ as required.

Comment: I think it is  $ -|\lambda_1| $  rather than  $ |\lambda_1| $  in  $ X $ .